# javascript - Enter key reloads the page

Tags: javascript, meteor

The Meteor template is reloading the page when the Enter key is pressed or when the button "info" is clicked instead of the expected behaviour which is firing the method `footerInfo`.
Any idea why and how to fire the method when either the button is tapped/pressed or the Enter key is hit? thx

```
Template.content.events({
  'keypress input': function (evt, template) {
    if (evt.which === 13) {
      $( "form" ).submit();
    }
  },
  'submit form': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    footerInfo();
  }
});

footerInfo = () => {
  //do stuff
};
```

```html
<head>
  <title>myApp</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="login-div">{{> loginButtons align='right'}}</div>
    <div id="content">
      <form>
        <button type="submit" style="display:none"></button>
        {{#if currentUser}}
          {{#if isVerified}}
            {{> content}}
            {{> footer}}
          {{else}}
            <p>Check your email for your verification link!</p>
          {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="content">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="plateNum">
    {{> results}}
  </form>
</template>

<template name="results">
  <p id="result">{{{display.alert}}}</p>
</template>

<template name="footer">
  <footer>
    <button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
    <button id="info">INFO</button>
  </footer>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you have two `form` tags in your code. You also do not need to listen for enter key events it is by default that the submit event will be fired when you press enter. To fix this first let remove the `form` tag in your content template:

```
<template name="content">
  <input type="text" id="plateNum">
  {{> results}}
</template>
```

Remove `keypress` and `submit` event listeners in `content` template, and add `submit` event listener in `body` template:

```
Template.body.events({
  'submit form': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    footerInfo();
  }
});
```